# Loop through Django context values

Tags: python, django, django-views

How do I render a context value as a key-value list in template?

```
def random_view(request):
   my_context = {
       "name": "turkey",
       "fly": "no",
       "run": 20
   }
   return render(request, 'test/test.html', my_context)
```

If this is the views the `views` then how can I loop through the values and render a list in `test.html` using a `loop`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it as a single variable:

```
def random_view(request):
    my_context = {
        'data': {
            'name': 'turkey',
            'fly': 'no',
            'run': 20
        }
    }
    return render(request, 'test/test.html', my_context)
```

Then in the template, you can loop over the `data` variable:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice. Do I always have to pass as a single variable?

Comment: @imRen: if you have to loop over it, you need to be able to reference it, so you need to pass the data as a variable yes.